# Enum error while doing check

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum like this

```
 public enum ConnectionState : int
   {
      Unknown = 1,
      Connected = 2,
      Disconnected = 3,
   }
```

I need to display value if it is connected i did this check

```
if(ConnectionState.Connected)
{
SubItems.Add(Data.value)
}
```

But i am getting an error "**Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConnectionState' to 'bool'"**.kindly suggest me how to proceed with this

Comment: You need to show some more code. You must have a variable of type ConnectionState(or int) to compare against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConnectionState` in this example is a type definition, you need to instantiate a ConnectionState object:

```
ConnectionState myState = new ConnectionState();
```

Then you can set your state:

```
myState = ConnectionState.Connected;
```

And check it with:

```
if(myState == ConnectionState.Connected)
```

Answer (score 6):

Should it not be something like

```
if(YourObject.ConnectionState == ConnectionState.Connected) 
{ 
    SubItems.Add(Data.value) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enums or enumerated data types ,as the name suggests are user defined datatypes.So they can not used directly in the condition statements.They can be compared within themselves.So you need to define your object and then compare its value with some other value in enum.